# Icon isn't working for entering sourcecode into a posting

Tags: discussion

I have programmed a chatbot which can enter sourcecode on AI.stackexchange. The problem is that the button for insert a codesnippet doesn't work, because the chatbot isn't able to find the correct location of the icon. Is it possible to use a different HTML form than the normal one of Stackexchange to simplify the edits?

*original message*

I just noticed something in AI stackexchange. Apparently we cannot insert pieces of code in the question or the answer i.e the java-script/HTML/CSS snippet. Why so?

I understand this site does not try to entertain implementation details, but still it would be a useful feature to have, to write algorithms in a beautiful way. What is the community's opinion on this and what should be done?

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking this could be in part of the variety of computers we could be on, the variety of the computing powers of said computers, and the variety of computation power required for various types of Neural Nets and such.

Say a specific piece of code works just fine on your Chromebook. This piece of code would also work just fine on any other device that can do parallel computations. This piece of code may still work on a RaspPi 3, but take 15-times longer to set up, train, test, etc.

What gets even worse is when the Library you use only supports a specific set of OS. You don't know what anyone seeing your question/answer uses.

So the main issue is the variety of computers out today, the variety of computation power supplied by those computers, and the variety of computation power required by various implementations of AI.

Therefore, not much can be done but test a piece of code on every device possible, and *then and only* then post the code. This becomes an issue when newcomers do not know about this. They may post a piece of code that works just fine on their computer, but results in disaster on others.